# Splunk query to use counter loop on earliest and latest date range

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

Refer below splunk spl query:

This query is giving the output for 1 day only, like below:
Column Header: HotScanMQ | Variance (i.e. Today_30May2023)

I want the output to be displayed in below format:
HotScanMQ | Variance Day1 (30May2023) | Variance Day2 (29May2023) | Variance Day3 (28May2023) | Variance Day4 (27May2023) for each day and so on until the Day 30. I want to use a counter to set "earliest" and "latest" sequentially and dynamically by giving a number range. Please suggest modification on this spl query accordingly.

```
index=app_events_reg_filtering_hotscan_de_prod source=*hotscan*hotscn*\/TODAY\/*hot*  "<--- TRN" "from" earliest=-7d@d latest=-7d@s 
| rex "\:  (?<hotgettrn>.*) \- S from"  
| rex "HOT\.RCV\.FROM\.(?<HotScanMQ>.*)\@" 
| eval Before7Day_Date = strftime(_time,"%Y-%m-%d") 
| stats count(hotgettrn) as HotGetBefore7Day by HotScanMQ, Before7Day_Date 
| append [ 
    search index=app_events_reg_filtering_hotscan_de_prod  source=*hotscan*hotscn*\/TODAY\/*hot*  "<--- TRN" "from" earliest=-0d@d latest=now 
    | rex "\: (?<hotgettrn>.*) \- S from"  
    | rex "HOT\.RCV\.FROM\.(?<HotScanMQ>.*)\@" 
    | eval Today = strftime(_time,"%Y-%m-%d")  
    | stats count(hotgettrn) as HotGetToday by HotScanMQ, Today 
  ] 
| stats values(*) as * by HotScanMQ 
| fillnull HotGetBefore7Day, HotGetToday value="0" 
| eval Today=if(isnull(Today) OR len(Today)==0,strftime(now(),"%Y-%m-%d"),Today) 
| eval Before7Day_Date=if(isnull(Before7Day_Date) OR len(Before7Day_Date)==0,strftime(relative_time(now(),"-7d@d"),"%Y-%m-%d"),Before7Day_Date) 
| eval Variance = case(HotGetBefore7Day > HotGetToday, round(((HotGetToday - HotGetBefore7Day) / HotGetBefore7Day) * 100,2), 
                HotGetBefore7Day < HotGetToday, round(((HotGetToday - HotGetBefore7Day) / HotGetToday) * 100,2), 
                HotGetBefore7Day = HotGetToday, round(((HotGetBefore7Day - HotGetToday) / HotGetToday) * 100,2)) 
| table HotScanMQ, Variance
```